# How to add elements to CopyInWriteCollection using Kotlin style?

Tags: kotlin, collections, immutability, immutable-collections

Assume we have a custom collection

```kotlin
class CopyOnWriteCollection<T> {

   // returns copy of collection with new element
   fun add(element: T): CopyOnWriteCollection<T> {
    ...
   }
}
```

if i need to add several elements i would do something like this:

```kotlin
val newCollection = oldCollection
    .add(1)
    .add(2)
    .add(3)
```

And `newCollection` contains elements from `oldCollection` and also contains 1,2,3. 
Perfect!

But how can i add elements from another collection using `forEach` of `map`?

```kotlin
val collection = CopyOnWriteCollection()
(1..3).forEach { collection.add(it) } // this approach works only with mutable collections
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an imperative loop, or you can use the `fold()`function:

```
fun main() {
    var collection = CopyOnWriteCollection<Int>()
    var collection2 = collection

    for (i in 1..3) {
        collection = collection.add(i)
    }

    println(collection)

    collection2 = (1..3).fold(collection2) { coll, i -> coll.add(i) }
    println(collection2)
}

class CopyOnWriteCollection<T> {

    private val list = mutableListOf<T>()

    // returns copy of collection with new element
    fun add(element: T): CopyOnWriteCollection<T> {
        val copy = CopyOnWriteCollection<T>()
        copy.list.addAll(this.list)
        copy.list.add(element)
        return copy;
    }

    override fun toString() = list.toString()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `CopyOnWriteCollection` class is under your control, I'd approach this by adding an `addAll()` method to it:

```
    /** Returns copy of collection with new element. */
    fun addAll(elements: Collection<T>): CopyOnWriteCollection<T> {
        // ...
    }
```

You could then call that with e.g.

```
val newCollection = oldCollection.addAll(listOf(1, 2, 3))
```

(Or you could take a `vararg` instead of a collection.)

That's likely to take a lot less time and memory.

(Also, if you really need to write your own collection class, I'd strongly recommend implementing `Collection` (or one of its subinterfaces if appropriate), or extending a class which does.  That will give access to the huge range of extension methods and other goodies in the stdlib.)